# Storing a pointer value for later use

Tags: c

I am storing a value in pointer `storeName` but when i try to access it later in program with a callback `storeName` is empty. I believe it is bz `name` in `parent` function is local. Changing `parent` function is not in my control. What is a best way to store value in `storeName` in `setName` function ,so `storeName` can be used later.

```
void parent()
{  
   uint8_t name[] = "James";
   setName(name);
}

static uint8_t* storeName;

void setName(uint8_t* name)
{
   storeName = name;
}
```

... at some other point in code

```
//*storeName is empty
```

(Note: above code is a simplified version just to explain the problem at hand)

Comment: storeName is not a pointer. "James" is not an 8 bit integer. This code is very odd.

Comment: sorry it was a typo. fixed now

Comment: The same goes for `name` in `parent` - the type is missing a `*`.

Comment: You didn't get any warnings when compiling this?  And what does it mean for a variable to be "empty"?

Comment: It will never work. The "James" data is dead once `parent` returns. Learn about scope and automatic variables.

Comment: @EugeneSh, no. String literals have program scope. In practice `storeName` should point to read-only memory.

Comment: @Benoit This is not string literal, strictly speaking. It is an array initializer. You can't take it's address. It is an alias of `{'J', 'a','m','e', 's', '\0'}`

Comment: @EugeneSh oh yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the address of a local variable.  The array `name` in `parent` goes out of scope once `parent` exits, so the pointer that pointed to that variable is now pointing to an unspecified memory location, and accessing it leads to undefined behavior.

If you define `name` like this:

```
uint8_t *name = "James";
```

Then it points to a constant string that lives in a read only section of memory which can be read safely outside of the function.  This differs from the previous declaration in that the constant string was used to initialize an array, where in this case you have a pointer to the actual constant.

Comment: This works with gcc. However, clang issues the following warning: `warning: initializing 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') with an
      expression of type 'char [6]' converts between pointers to integer types with
      different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
   uint8_t *name  = "James" ;`